# How to hibernate raspberry pi4? suspend-to-disk, aka power off state

Tags: pi-4

I apologize for the lack of knowledge.

I am attempting to Hibernate / leave all open applications open, unplug power take the PI somewhere else and reboot starting up right where I left off.

This way if I am working on multiple documents I can hibernate and take the PI4 somewhere else without saving everything closing everything and shutting down.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `walk away without saving` .... bad practice .... always save your work .... `walk away without shutting down apps` is ok

Comment: Try `systemctl hibernate` from the terminal. **MAKE SURE TO SAVE ANY OPEN WORK BEFORE YOU DO THIS.**

Comment: Those 2 comment votes for user96931 above are wasted; there is **no support** in any available Raspberry Pi hardware, not in any supplied OS kernel, for either hibernate or suspend.

Comment: So to follow up:

End Goal: PI mobility without shutting down. Switch from wall to battery and back

How I accomplished this: HOT SWAP.  Disclaimer: I am willing to loose my files on my PI so don't try this at work.

Using GPIO Pin 3 --V5 and Pin 5 --Ground  | some 18650's | and a DC-DC XL4015 to buck regulate the voltage from batteries down to 5v.  I connect the output from my XL4015 into Pin's 3 and 5 and leave it at all times.  While running from Type C power input I will plug the batteries into the XL4015 and then disconnect the type C and vice versa to go from batteries to wall.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible. None of the Raspberry Pis have ever had a "low power" or "sleeping" or "not quite dead yet" mode. Hibernation doesn't exist in any OS I've ever run on a Raspberry Pi.

You have two choices.

1. Leave it running - it costs less than £5 to run a RPi for 366 days.
2. Get external hardware like a WittyPi2 to power down and restart on a timer schedule.

Save your work, then if the power drops you'll be OK. All of my Raspberry Pis survived a 3.5hour loss of mains.